# Getting the precise location of my device

Tags: python, geolocation

I have been using the geocoder module in Python to try to get my location, but it, alongside the Google Maps API return latitude and longitude data which is really inaccurate:

`{'location': {'lat': 51.4555904, 'lng': -2.5952256}, 'accuracy': 2512.67034496449}`

and it is far from where I actually am.

I am looking for a module, or a way to solve this, which will allow me to constantly track my position with high accuracy.

Comment: There are lots of ways to get the location of an object, other than GPS, and the "best" depends entirely on what you are trying to do. I.e. indoors, outdoors, the area to track over, your budget. You can also filter the position data from GPS with the accelerometer data using a Kalman filter.

Comment: @TomMcLean I am trying to use GPS for outdoor data. I am making an app which is supposed to help users see the best route from A to B while tracking their position.